# latex table landscape

Tags: latex, landscape, tabular

I am writing a tabel in latex in landscape style.

my code is this one:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
   \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
    & \textbf{IEEE} & \textbf{CODATA} & \textbf{ACM} & \textbf{Springer Verlag} & \textbf{ELSEVIER} & \textbf{IOS PRESS} \\ 
    \hline
    Journal & Journal Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering & Data Science Journal & Journal of Data and Information Quality & International Journal of Data Science & Computional Statistics and Data Analysis & Data Science Journal \\
    \hline
    Organisation bzw. Verlag & Organisation & Organisation & Organisation & Verlag & Verlag & Verlag \\
    \hline
    Mitglieder bzw. Mitarbeiter & 400.000 Mitglieder & - & 78.000 Mitglieder & 15.323 (2016) Mitarbeiter & 30.500 (2011) Mitarbeiter & - \\
    \hline
    Editoren & Editor-in-Chief Xuemin Lin Editors-in-Chief Lei Chen & Editor-in-Chief Sarah Callaghan & - & Editor-in-Chief Longbing Cao & Co-Editors A.M. Colubi E.J. Kontoghiorghes B.U. Park & Editors-in-Chief Michel Dumontier Tobias Kuhn \\
    \hline
    Links & \url{http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=69} & \url{https://datascience.codata.org/} & \url{https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=J1191} & \url{http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+\%26+information+retrieval/journal/41060} & \url{https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computational-statistics-and-data-analysis/} & \url{https://www.iospress.nl/journal/data-science/} \\
    \hline
    Erstausgabe Jahr & 1989 & 2002 & 2009 & 2016 & 1983 & 2017 \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Übersicht der Konkurrenten}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

My problem is, when i compile my .tex file, the lines are not pulled through the end.

Here is a picture:
[image: Picture of the PDF]

I really appreciate any answers!

Comment: [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) requires at least one `X`-column in order to work.

Comment: thanks @Werner for the information. I was just asking myself, if there is another possibility to set the table to the full length of the page? I think setting the size with 24cm is not the best solution.

Comment: Yes, you can use `\textwidth` or `\textheight` for lengths related to the text block. Sometimes it's better to use `\linewidth` (instead of `\textwidth`) if you're setting a table inside a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i fixed it by editing the table.

I now use

```
\begin{tabularx}{24cm}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
```